# TypeLoadException: Method from assembly does not have an implementation while it does. Cannot be resolved despite numerous cleanups

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, typeloadexception

I've returned to my program (console application) after two months. It was working fine before. But suddenly I get this error. I'm using `Google API` in the program:

[image]

I have cleaned my solution and build anew. Cleared both my `bin` and `obj` folders and tried again.

I even started to create a new project and copied the code and loaded the `DLL` files but the same error shows up.

I have read some other posts about this `TypeLoadException` but they mostly address that I have different versions of the `DLL` in two places that confuses the program.

But it's not true. And the method actually does have an implementation.  Because it was working perfectly before.

I do not understand what has happened in these two months. All there is that I have bought a new laptop. But I check the program on my old laptop as well and it does not work there either.

I should add that the project is also on `Github`. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I can be wrong but is this method something you should have implemented in your own code (like Interface or abstract class)? If positive please provide the implementation in your question.

Comment: Some actual code might be useful too.

Comment: @VitorCanova No. I just had to add it as a reference. I don't implement anything on it.